# Difference in the number of arrivals of a Poisson process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Say k > 0, t $\geq$ 0 and $N_{t}$ is a Poisson Process with rate $\lambda$ >0 ;

Is $$M(t) = \dfrac{N_{t+k^2} - N_{t}}{k}$$ a Poisson Process?

The answer is clearly no since the above process is not a counting process. However I don't exactly understand what would happen if k were to be 1. Would m(t) be a PP for k=1? Intuitively, I feel like for k=1, the given M(t) should be a PP but some very good questions were raised by my friend who asked how we would try to satisfy the property of independent increments for a Poisson process. A detailed explanation would be appreciated.

Edit:  For clarification, can we say that if $N_{t}$ satisfies independent increments, $M(t)=M(t)\big|_{k=1}$ will have independent increments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$M$ does not have independent increments. Let $s < t$. Then

$$ M(t) - M(s) = [N(t+1) - N(s+1)] - [N(t) - N(s)]. $$

From this, we note that

$$ \mathbf{Cov}(M(2) - M(1), M(1) - M(0))
= -\mathbf{Var}(N(2) - N(1))
= -\lambda. $$

So $M(2) - M(1)$ and $M(1) - M(0)$ are not independent.

That $M$ is not a Poisson process can be verified by other means:

- $M(t)\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$ does not depend on $t$, which is contrary to the Poisson processes.
- The sample paths of $M$ are not monotone increasing almost surely. On the other hand, Poisson sample paths are monotone increasing with probability one.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the last bullet point?

Comment: @Harduin, Imagine you draw the graph of the function $t\mapsto N_t(\omega)$. It is of course random, but whenever you observe its values (i.e., if you fix a sample $\omega$), you certainly obtain a function in time $t$. (This graph is often called a sample path.) Now, since $N_t$ is a counting process, this function will be monotone increasing. How about if we investigate this question for the process $M$? The graph of the function $t\mapsto M_t(\omega)$ will 'fluctuate' rather than increase.